# Equally distanced buttons appear blurry

Tags: android, layout, imagebutton

I have 4 ImageButton in a linearlayout placed equally distanced. For now I am using one background for all 4 ImageButtons and size of resource is 36x36.

ImageButton appears stretched and  blurry. What am I doing wrong?

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_buttons"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_tabbar_tile"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/play"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/play"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/play1"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/play"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/play2"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/play"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/play3"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/play"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, background drawables are stretched to the size of the containing view. You can avoid this by using a BitmapDrawable. Put this in a new XML file in `res/drawable`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:src="@drawable/play"
      android:gravity="center" />
```

Then use this new drawable instead of `@drawable/play` in your image buttons.

Comment: does it matter what I name xml file?

Comment: Perfect answer...here is what I did...in drawable folder created button.xml which has
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap android:src="@drawable/play"
      android:gravity="center" 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>

and in layout instead of doing @drawable/play do @drawable/button

Comment: @Abid - You can name it anything. Sorry that I left out the xmlns attribute. I'll edit my answer to include that, in case anyone else tries to imitate this.